# Replacing specific field using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Iwant to update these two fields(client and environment) by using regex script function

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="AIR.client.environment.value" loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" />
</authentication>
```

the function that i have

```
$regex_clientname = new-object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("client=.*", [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase);
$regex_enviorenment = new-object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("environment=.*", [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::IgnoreCase);

$root.SelectSingleNode("//authentication/forms/@name")."#text"=$regex_enviorenment.Replace($regex_clientname.Replace($root.SelectSingleNode("//authentication/forms/@name")."#text", $CLIENT),$ENV);
```

but it is not updating.. i need help

Comment: I still don't see any relevance for c++!!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, not sure how your reading in the XML but try this:

```
$nodes = $root | Select-Xml '//authentication/forms/@name'
$nodes | Foreach { $_.Node.Value = ($_.Node.Value -replace '(.*?)client(.*)',"`$1${CLIENT}`$2") -replace '(.*?)environment(.*)',"`$1${ENV}`$2"}
$root.Save('path')
```

Note that to persist the XML file changes you need to call `Save()` on the xml document object.

Comment: $CLIENT and $ENV is the input variables. but i dont know how to convert your script in to mines.